# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to add int values in a gridview. Heres my C# code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows) 
{
      int I = (Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[5].Text) 
              + Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[6].Text) 
              + Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[7].Text) 
              + Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[8].Text) 
              + Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[9].Text));
      r.Cells[10].Text = Convert.ToString(I);
}
```

> Exception: "Input string was not in a correct format"

It was working fine earlier. I switched to another system, attached the database, made a few changes here & there and its not working now. The gridview cells already have values when the page is loaded. I am just adding (sum) those values and displaying the addition in another cell of the same gridview on the click of a button.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what kind of values are you trying to convert? have you an example?

Comment: Did you debug that line? All cell values are convertable to int?

Comment: adding a break point at for each loop and debugging the loop would have taken much less time than typing the question here, and you would have got answer as well. :)

Comment: i did debug. its taking all nulls (""). hows that possible when the gridview is already displaying the values on page load..?

Comment: in my database i have taken the datatype for all these values as float. however while entering the values, i have entered integers. now the gridview displays the values (integers) when the page is loaded. howver when i click the button, it sends all null values...

Answer (score 5):

Check the value passed in to each of the `Convert.ToInt32` calls, one or more of them is not convertible to `int`.

You can do this by looking directly at the source in your database manager, or step through the code and watch the row columns and values, etc. However you do, the fix remains the same and takes one or both of two forms: fix the data, or fix the code to care not (if that is acceptable).

You may be interested in [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) for the latter purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int val1 = 0;
            int val2 = 0;
            int val3 = 0;
            int val4 = 0;
            int val5 = 0;

            int.TryParse(r.Cells[5].Text, out val1);
            int.TryParse(r.Cells[6].Text, out val1);
            int.TryParse(r.Cells[7].Text, out val1);
            int.TryParse(r.Cells[8].Text, out val1);
            int.TryParse(r.Cells[9].Text, out val1);

            int I = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5);

            r.Cells[10].Text = I.ToString();
        }
```

You should always test values before attempting to convert to another data type where possible.

Comment: Without actually seeing the data I can't really give you an answer other than there must have been some odd data that didn't want to play nice.

Comment: the data was integer values with (datatype as float in the database)... thnx thoh

Comment: Then the data you have can't be converted to int. As you have said the data is stored as float then I can only assume you have values containing a point i.e. 3.5 - this will not convert to int, you will need to either round it up or down first. Or change your code to handle floats using float.TrParse() and then sum the floats.

Comment: only the Datatype is Float. The values contained (inserted) are integers. Also, I have tried using a float type variable and Convert.ToFloat()... looks like C# doesnt support Convert.ToFloat(). it supports Convert.ToDouble() thoh... and m not really sure how to use float.tryparse()...

Comment: If you're only storing integers can you not alter the data type of the column? Does it have to be a float? You use float.TryParse() the same as I used int.TryParse() in my example except val1-5 will be floats.

Answer (score 0):

Check the RowType of the GridViewRow when you are iterating. It might be that you are trying to parse values from a HeaderRow. I think you are only interested in DataRows.

Also, you might want to consider not getting values from your gridview using indexes on the cells. If you change the layout of your gridview your calculation will fail.

Comment: I set the row type to data rows...
foreach()
{
 if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{ // my code
}
}

its still not working.. i cud really use some help here...

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a null value to a meaningful value through Convert.  Your best option is to check for null first and then assign a value of 0 (or whatever) to the result (wherever Convert was sending its results too).